# How to handle click events inside bootstrap button dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The change events inside the bootstrap button dropdown is not functioning. What could be the reason? How to fix this?

Below is my fiddle. I wanted to fire a checkbox changed event but surprisingly the below code doesn't fire.

`http://jsfiddle.net/20hLtzvr/18/`

```
 $('#chk0').click(function()
    {
    alert('hello world');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `"` when you set the id

Replace

```
$('#citycountylist ul').append('<li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" id=' + 'chk' + index + ' />' + '&nbsp;' + json.NewYork[index].name + ' </a></li>');
```

By

```
$('#citycountylist ul').append('<li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="' + 'chk' + index + '" />' + '&nbsp;' + json.NewYork[index].name + ' </a></li>');
```